# How does this implementation of a ternary operator work?

Tags: scala, ternary-operator

I've used this implementation of a scala ternary operator quite a lot recently especially with toggling enable/disabled images, however, I usually can understand code snippets I find, this has been confusing me. I also want to modify it slightly to better suit my needs. I like the operator-ish syntax over verbose if else blocks etc.

```
implicit def BooleanBool(b: Boolean): Bool = Bool(b)

case class Bool(b: Boolean) {
  def ?[X](t: => X) = new {
    def |(f: => X) = if (b) t else f
  }
}
```

So I understand the implicit creates a Bool object, with ? as a function. That function must return a value of type X. The rest I struggle to understand.

Heres my questions:

1. How does the nested function work? the | function.
2. What order does the code actually resolve?
3. How can I change it so there is the option to have no else clause? eg. isTheSkyBlue() ? goOutside()
4. Is there a downside to nesting ternary operators eg:

   ```
   isTheSkyBlue() ? goOutside() | {
       isTheInternetOn() ? playVideoGame() | read() 
   }
   ```
5. Could the nest be changed to act like a case statement. Ie use a => operator or similar. eg.

   ```
   isTheSkyBlue() ? goOutside() | =>
       isTheInternetOn() ? playVideoGame() | read()
   ```

   Or even get rid of it all together

   ```
   isTheSkyBlue() ? goOutside() |
       isTheInternetOn() ? playVideoGame() | read()
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer 1 and 2, the nested function is pretty simple, the characters `?` `|` are just method names. I renamed `?` to `question` and `|` to `or` and added in the explicit call to `Bool`. This is what it looks like de-sugared:

```
  case class Bool(b: Boolean) {
    def question[X](t: => X) = new {
      def or(f: => X) = if (b) t else f
    }
  }

  Bool(isTheSkyBlue()).question(goOutside()).or(
    Bool(isTheInternetOn()).question(playVideoGame()).or(read())
  )
```

3 is a little tougher because `if` requires an `else` otherwise what would it be returning? If you're only doing a side effect then you could do something like this:

```
  implicit def OneWayBooleanBool(b: Boolean): OneWayBool = OneWayBool(b)

  case class OneWayBool(b: Boolean) {
    def ??[X](t: => X) = if (b) t
  }

  isTheSkyBlue() ?? goOutside()
```

For question 4, there's no real issue with nesting except for complicated code.

For question 5, you can't really do this because of how scala will resolve things, unless someone else out there has an idea how to do this.

Comment: So is the new{...} creating an anonymous object with a function "or"? then evaluating t or f depending on the boolean? I understand it a lot better now thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Complementing @Noah's answer:

The `?` function isn't returning a value of type `X`, it's returning an anonymous class. We could make it an ordinary class (ignoring laziness for the moment):

```
class PartiallyEvaluated[X](b: Boolean, t: X) {
  def |(f: X) = if(b) t else f
}
class Bool(b: Boolean) {
  def ?[X](t: X) = new PartiallyEvaluated(b, t)
}
```

Scala always resolves `a b c d e` as `a.b(c).d(e)`. If you're willing to add an "end chain" method then you can make the first expression return some kind of lazy thing that knows what to do when called on another object. Or you could maybe make a `for`/`yield` syntax for chains of these things, but I suspect that would be more confusing than helpful.